# Fabric Crashlytics for Unity : how can i get line num in Stacktrace with c# on Android?

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

I am using Fabric Crashlytics for Unity, now i get the Stacktrace for c#, but i cannot get the line number.

Unity version:5.5.1p4

Fabric Crashlytics version:1.2.5

Android Configuration of Scripting Backend is IL2CPP.

This is the Stacktrace :

[image]
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. Currently, our Unity exception reporting does not include line numbers.

Comment: Thank you. Has plan add Unity exception reporting line num ?

Comment: It's not on our immediate roadmap.

Comment: Sentry did, here are the docs: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/unity/configuration/il2cpp/

Answer (score 0):

You can get Line Numbers in C# Exceptions with IL2CPP when using Sentry to capture errors and crashes. Works on Android, iOS, Windows, macOS and Linux builds.

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/unity/configuration/il2cpp/